# Git failed with a fatal error. when push code to git hub using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Git failed with a `fatal error`.

This is the error I get:

```
open(MobileApp/.vs/MobileApp/v16/Server/sqlite3/db.lock): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path MobileApp/.vs/MobileApp/v16/Server/sqlite3/db.lock (without quotes):
     error occur.Any one know how to fix this
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because of `.vs` file. You have to make `.gitignore` file and put `.vs` file inside it. I think it will work.